# Unable to load Google Maps API with Geolocation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I followed the documentation on Google itself regarding the Map API and other sources to try to figure out what's wrong but after a few hours of trying it still doesnt work..

Could anyone please guide me into solving it?

```
<div class="generatedMap"></div>
                <div class="generatedMap"></div>
                <script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&client=gme-KEYFROMGOOGLEAPI" type="text/javascript"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function initMap() {
                        /*var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                        var mapOptions = {
                            zoom: 5,
                            center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude)
                        }
                        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('generatedMap'), mapOptions);*/

                        var latitudeHF = document.getElementById("<%=HF_Latitude.ClientID %>");
                        var longitudeHF = document.getElementById("<%=HF_Longitude.ClientID %>");

                        var latitude = 0.0;
                        var longitude = 0.0;

                        if (latitudeHF)
                        {
                            latitude = latitudeHF.value;
                        }

                        if (longitudeHF) {
                            longitude = longitudeHF.value;
                        }

                        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('generatedMap'), {
                            zoom: 8,
                            center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
                        });

                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
                            map: map,
                            title: "<div style = 'height:60px;width:150px'><b>Consumer's location:</b><br />Latitude: " + latitude + "<br />Longitude: " + longitude
                        });
                    }

                    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
                </script>
```

I'm actually retrieving the saved latitude and longitude from my database, then storing it into a HiddenField and retrieving it from there..

```
foreach (DataRow r in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            accountDB = r["AccountStatus"].ToString();
            latitudeDB = Convert.ToDouble(r["Latitude"]);
            longitudeDB = Convert.ToDouble(r["Longitude"]);
            usernameDB = r["Username"].ToString();
            ipDB = r["IPAddressOfCreation"].ToString();
        }

HF_Latitude.Value = latitudeDB.ToString();
HF_Longitude.Value = longitudeDB.ToString();
```

I removed the Google Map API key for illustration purposes..

I got both the latitude and longitude displayed as shown in the picture but i cant seem to display the map..

[image: display]

Appreciate any help please!

Comment: As per your code you are using creating a class and then you are retrieving in javascript code as like Id.So due to this reason map is not displaying please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mistake into your code in Div tag instead of `class` you need to define `id` as attributes.**

It's better you just this script src for google map.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=Google-api-key&callback=initMap" />
```

Once you are using above script src then remove this line from your code.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

**Instead of :**

```
<div class="generatedMap"></div>
```

**Should be :**

```
<div id="generatedMap"></div>
```

**Javascript code will remain as it is. if you wanted to keep class as it is then use blow code in javascript**

**Instead of :**

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('generatedMap')
```

**Should be :**

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementsByClassName('generatedMap')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Emipro, thank you for your correction. I will try it later. In a lecture at the moment. Will get back here. Thanks!